# Java ответ от серера HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection

Здравствуйте. Отправляю запрос на сервер и должен получить от него Json но получаю ответ непонятного содержания:

```
4M�
```

��X\���?�@� eqI/��x}׉۽����������I��^&�^   ح�\t�ko��Izk�E��_������'\V�뻿��ه9ªTM+m
`���0X�̆ihʔ��"qw�m   O�{��B�!��U�-��e`Tt�d�Y࢔��3$U��׳z.@.�'�����&�݊F��բ���S�s�ڥ-d9T�M����AJ�3�
J���iD4a}�\2/F|����"G�eSiX��AcP��i"ns��*������b�_z�橳Rq�3Tg*�A���w7(ֶ$=�
�(0ph��mV��qܦ���0�E��nKn�Ik�T!�3>�
c���w�-�~���V`�<�1fQ
Сначала думал дело в кодировках, но даже по байтам не получается расшифровать ответ. В строке ответа часто встречается символ под номером 65533. Подскажите где искать ошибку.

Comment: Есть подозрения что это сжатый ответ. Попробуйте отредактировать Accept-Encoding в хидере запроса.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы!!!

Comment: @Russtam добавьте ответом

Answer (score 3):

Как написал Russtam: сервер присылает сжатый ответ. Для разархивации использовал следующий код:

```
    DataInputStream inStream = new                                       
    DataInputStream(reqConn.getInputStream());
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(inStream);
    InputStreamReader readerGzip = new InputStreamReader(gzip);
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(readerGzip);
    String reddd;
    while ((reddd = bufReader.readLine()) != null){
        buffer.append(reddd);
    }
```